# Fazer com que ao clicar no botao apareça o texto e a imagem especifica?

Tags: java, android

Quero fazer um projeto onde ao clicar no botão irá aparecer um texto e quando aparecer o texto quero que apareça uma imagem junto. ex: texto randomico escolhido "o cachorro é bobo" aparece a foto do cachorro.

segue meu codigo atual

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    private Button botaoIniciar;
    private TextView texto;
    private ImageView imagem;

    private String[] frases = {"O CACHORRO E BOBO",
            "O GATO E MIMADO", "A BALEIA É ROSA",
            "O RATO ROEU O QUEIJO", "A MAMÃE FEZ UMA SOPA",
            "A BUZINA É DO CAMINHÃO","O PAPAI É MUITO BONITO",
            "A MAMÃE É MUITO LINDA", };

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


        botaoIniciar = (Button) findViewById(R.id.botaoIniciarId);
        texto = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textoId);
        imagem = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imagemId);

        botaoIniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                Random numeroRandomico = new Random();
                int numeroAleatorio = numeroRandomico.nextInt(frases.length);
                texto.setText(frases[numeroAleatorio]);
                getImagem();
            }

        });

    }

    public void getImagem() {

        if (texto.equals("O CACHORRO E BOBO")) {
            imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.cao);
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "imagem não encotrada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual é o problema com o seu código?

Comment: o problema é que não consigo achar o erro, pq não exibe a imagem junto com o texto. caso o texto for o cachorro é bobo era para aparecer a imagem do cao, mas não aparece,

Comment: Em vez de `texto.equals("O CACHORRO E BOBO")` use `texto.getText().toString().equals("O CACHORRO E BOBO")`

Comment: opa, muito obrigado, também deu certo!

Answer (score 2):

A solução mais direta para o que pretende é criar um array de id's com os ids de cada imagem e que correspondem aos textos no array `frases`:

```
private String[] frases = {
        "O CACHORRO E BOBO",
        "O GATO E MIMADO", 
        "A BALEIA É ROSA",
        "O RATO ROEU O QUEIJO", 
        "A MAMÃE FEZ UMA SOPA",
        "A BUZINA É DO CAMINHÃO",
        "O PAPAI É MUITO BONITO",
        "A MAMÃE É MUITO LINDA", 
};

private int[] drawables = {
        R.drawable.cao,
        R.drawable.gato,
        R.drawable.baleia,
        R.drawable.rato,
        R.drawable.mamae_sopa,
        R.drawable.buzina,
        R.drawable.papai,
        R.drawable.mamae_linda,
};
```

Depois apenas no click do define a frase e a imagem com base no mesmo número aleatório sorteado:

```
botaoIniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Random numeroRandomico = new Random();
        int numeroAleatorio = numeroRandomico.nextInt(frases.length);
        texto.setText(frases[numeroAleatorio]);

        //aplicar a imagem correspondente
        imagem.setImageResource(drawables[numeroAleatorio]);
    }
});
```

Se quiser dar a possibilidade de não ter imagens para todos os textos, pode iniciar as que não tem com `-1` e mudar o código de click para:

```
botaoIniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Random numeroRandomico = new Random();
        int numeroAleatorio = numeroRandomico.nextInt(frases.length);
        texto.setText(frases[numeroAleatorio]);

        //agora testa se tem a imagem correspondente antes de aplicar    
        if (drawables[numeroAleatorio] != -1){
            imagem.setImageResource(drawables[numeroAleatorio]);
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "imagem não encotrada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

### Organizando com uma classe

Se começar a ter várias informações separadas para cada elemento o melhor é criar uma classe que agrupa essas informações:

```
public class Imagem {
    private String texto;
    private int drawable;

    public Imagem(String texto, int drawable){
        this.texto = texto;
        this.drawable = drawable;
    }

    public String getTexto(){
        return texto;
    }

    public int getDrawable(){
        return drawable;
    }
}
```

Depois em vez de construir os 2 arrays que foram exemplificados acima, passaria a construir um array destes objetos:

```
private Imagem[] imagens = {
    new Imagem("O CACHORRO E BOBO", R.drawable.cao),
    new Imagem("O GATO E MIMADO", R.drawable.gato),
    new Imagem("A BALEIA É ROSA", R.drawable.baleia),
    new Imagem("A MAMÃE FEZ UMA SOPA", -1),
    new Imagem("A BUZINA É DO CAMINHÃO", R.drawable.buzina),
    new Imagem("O PAPAI É MUITO BONITO", R.drawable.papai),
    new Imagem("A BUZINA É DO CAMINHÃO", -1),
    new Imagem("A MAMÃE É MUITO LINDA", R.drawable.mamae)
};
```

Agora o click obtem o elemento sorteado e desse elemento extrai todas as informações:

```
botaoIniciar.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        Random numeroRandomico = new Random();
        int numeroAleatorio = numeroRandomico.nextInt(frases.length);
        Imagem escolhida = imagens[numeroAleatorio];

        texto.setText(escolhida.getTexto());

        //agora testa se tem a imagem correspondente antes de aplicar    
        if (escolhida.getDrawable() != -1){
            imagem.setImageResource(escolhida.getDrawable());
        }
        else {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "imagem não encotrada",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: MUITOOOO OBRIGADO PELA INFORMAÇÃO! ME AJUDOU DEMAIS!!!

Comment: @senderrodriguesdossantos Sem problema. Fico contente de ter ajudado

Comment: Isac, me tire mais uma duvida, no caso vc disse para trabalhar com uma classe para agrupar essas informações e depois criar uma array de objetos. poderia exemplificar algo do tipo?

Comment: @senderrodriguesdossantos Já editei a resposta para contemplar esse exemplo.